# How to say a specific day of the month

Tags: traducción

How does one say something like "at the 5th of December" in Spanish ?
Is it like telling the time (e.g. "a las cinco del Diciembre") ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either say:

> El cinco de diciembre.

or:

> El día cinco de diciembre.

emphasizing the day.

When it's the first day you can say:

> El primero de diciembre

or:

> El día primero del mes.

Comment: + 1 por _enfatizar_ el día en la traducción.

Answer (score 3):

The translation should be:

> El cinco de diciembre.

Where in this case, you should *ommit* the word "the" in the translation:

So, the result will be:

> The 5th of December.

And there, you'll get an adequate translation.

Comment: Como regla en español, los meses no empiezan con mayúscula, a menos que el mes esté al principio de la oración.

Comment: Excepción: cuando el nombre del mes forma parte del nombre de una festividad o fecha señalada. Por ejemplo, la fiesta mexicana del *Cinco de Mayo*.

Answer (score -1):

"El cinco de diciembre" 
The month name in lowercase.